# How to replay pcap network packets files from a website programmatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, backend, pcap

I want to replay a .pcap file from a website. I am building a network traffic monitor android application and I want to test it against prerecorded malicious packets as .pcap file. I want my website to replay the packets automatically when the website is opened. Is it possible to create a piece of code in that can make it happen ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic, because playing back WireShark packetlogs has no relation to programming. Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I disagree; I can't imagine that a non-programmer would want to do that.  Voting to leave open.